# Area of triangle as a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am having a hard time with the following question

Let $P_0,P_1,P_2$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We denote $r_i = P_0P_i, i =1,2$. Let P be the 2 by 2 matrix with rows $r_1$ and $r_2$. Let A denote the area of the triangle with vertices $P_0,P_1,P_2$. Explain why $A=\frac{1}{2}|\det(P)|$

Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hints: There's a relationship between the 2x2 determinant and the cross product in the plane. We also have the geometric formula for triangle area $\mathit{Area} = \frac{1}{2} bc \sin A$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Are you familiar with the determinant of a 3x3 matrix being the volume of the parallelepiped whose edges are the three rows?  A similar fact holds in two dimensions.  You might try expressing the sides of the triangle both with magnitude and angle and also with components. A trigonometry identity about the difference of two angles might come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can choose a coordinate system so that the origin is at one angle of the triangle and the x-axis lies upon one side of the triangle.

In that coordinate system, the vertices of the triangle are (0, 0), (b, 0), and (a, h).  The are of the triangle is 1/2 height times base= bh/2.

Taking P0= (0, 0), P1P0= (b, 0) and P2P0= (a, h).  The determinant is $\left|\begin{array}{cc}b & 0 \\ a & h\end{array}\right|= bh$

Answer (score 2):

There's a small error in notation: the rows are made up of the coordinates of the vectors $\vec{P_0P_i}$.

*Hint*: it is a basic result on determinants that the absolute value of this determinant is the area of the parallelogram built on these vectors.